# Possible null reference argument for parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am currently using Visual studio 2022, below is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].TenantDetails != null)
                dtEntity = DataTableManager.ConvertData(list[i].TenantDetails);
        }
```

---

```
public static DataTable ConvertData(byte[] data) { ... }
```

Getting the below warning.
Warning CS8604  Possible null reference argument for parameter 'data' in 'DataTable DataTableManager.ConvertData(byte[] data)'

How to avoid this warning? After converting my old project from VS 2019 to 2022 I am getting lot of code warnings.

Comment: You probably have nullable references enabled, which means you have to take extra care. What ***exactly*** and ***precisely*** is the type of the `.TenantDetails` member?

Comment: public partial class Tenant
    {
        public byte[]? TenantDetails { get; set; }
    }
If I remove the "?" in byte[] it gives another warning - Warning CS8618 Non-nullable property 'TenantDetails' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

Comment: So you've said that `TenantDetails` is `byte[]?`, the question mark at the end signals that the property *may* be `null`. Yet, `ConvertData` takes `byte[]`, without the question mark. I know you have the if-statement there but the compiler is not smart enough always, so you might have to use `!` after the parameter, or you can do `var details = list[i].TenantDetails;`, and then use that in both if-statement and parameter, then the compiler sees that it's guaranteed to be the same value.

Comment: I guess the fact that it doesn't know what reading `list[i]` does trips it up.

Comment: I am sure I am going to assign value to below property while intializing the object.
public byte[]? TenantDetails { get; set; }
But Is there a way to remove "?" and get rid of Warning CS8618 Non-nullable property 'TenantDetails' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to remove "?" and get rid of Warning CS8618 Non-nullable property 'TenantDetails' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor

You can try to set default value for `TenantDetails`.

```
public byte[] TenantDetails { get; set; } =new byte[0];
```

And you can try to check `TenantDetails.Length`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list[i].TenantDetails.Length>0)
                dtEntity = DataTableManager.ConvertData(list[i].TenantDetails);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get rid of these warnings using a .editorconfig file.

Go to a warning a position the cursor to see the possible solutions, there are two options: "suppress on source" or the below one which is like suppress in the  solution. Click on that one and an .editor config file will be created for you and the warning will just gone.